# How to refresh QTableView during SQLite table update?

Tags: c++, sql, multithreading, qt, sqlite

I use C++/Qt 4.8, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, SQLite 3.8.1. My GUI application contains several threads: the default GUI-thread, master thread, some worker threads. The master thread handles worker threads. Workers emit signals which ask the master to update some cells of the table in the SQLite database. 
So, there 2 database connections: 1 for GUI thread, `QTableView`, `QSqlTableModel` descendant and 1 for the master thread. Master emits signal which asks GUI-thread to update `QTableView`. How should `QTableView` be updated considering SQLite row count problem (requires canFetchMore())? I don't want update_slot() to be computationally intensive. The master thread generates only "UPDATE table" queries. Should I update table without SQL in order to emit `dataChanged` signal? I've read that `QSqlTableModel` is a high-level alternative to `QSqlQuery` for navigating and modifying individual SQL tables. It typically results in less code and requires no knowledge of SQL syntax.
I have met such code to update QTableView (SQLite can't directly get the row count):

```
m_result_table_model->select();
while(m_result_table_model->canFetchMore()) 
{
  m_result_table_model->fetchMore();            
}
```

Should this code be called after each row update? When I used `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` in the `update_slot()`, I got stack overflow exception.

Comment: 1) What exactly do you mean by "row count problem (requires ...)"? 2) What computation exactly do you have that is heavy? 3) How would you update the table without SQL? 4) What exactly is the problem with a computation heavy worker method?

Comment: 1. SQLite does not have rowCount feature. 2. I mean that I want to make only relevant cells updates in `QTableView`. 3. Using QSqlTableModel. 4. I don't want frequent repopulating of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to force QSqlQueryModel to refresh some rows. You can only clear it and refill it with new data as you've described. If this is not fast enough, you should implement this behavior manually. The options are to create your own model class, subclass QSqlTableModel or use QStandardItemModel.